# How can I build openssl with debug symbols ? [add libeay.pdb]

Tags: c++, build, openssl, pdb-files

I am using openssl, and I get lots and lots of warnings during build about missing **libeay.pdb**. Can somebody suggest how to add it ?

the build.cmd looks like this (significant piece I think):

```
...
perl util\mk1mf.pl debug dll no-asm VC-WIN64A >ms\ntdll64.dbg.mak
perl util\mkdef.pl 32 libeay > ms\libeay32.def
nmake -f ms/nt64.dbg.mak
```

I read the INSTALL.W32 which says "If you use the platform debug-VC-WIN32 instead of VC-WIN32 then debugging symbols will be compiled in." I Tried to replace VC-WIN64A with debug-WIN64A (same with 32), and the build gave me an error

```
Unknown option --debug-VC-WIN64A
```

Thank you.

Edit: It worked when I added /DEBUG after mak
Edit again: /DEBUG was not necessary, the **debug** word in the command did the work.
How do I build it with Visual Studio ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you build OpenSSL on Windows with Visual Studio, the symbols file for the library is named `lib.pdb`, and it's located in the `tmp32` directory, so you might need to manually copy it into the `out32` directory.

This was true for the Win32 configuration as of version 1.0.0g; it's possible that that's changed since then, and it's possible it might be different for Win64.

Comment: You *are* building it with Visual Studio -- the compiler, not the IDE.  The `nmake` utility invokes the compiler (`cl.exe`) from the command line.